# Low poly pose with decimate and replacing it with high res

Tags: modeling, rendering, pose-mode

I have a high poly model and want to pose it. How can i use the model with a decimate and pose it and later replace it or get back the detail from the high poly one?

Comment: There is a way (mind the order of modifiers) to pose the high poly and then decimate them. Do you have to decimate it before posing it and making it high poly AGAIN?

Comment: Yes, cant pose the high poly.. I would decimate the model and then pose it and then replace it with a high poly version before i decimated it.